# Keep same random numbers - matlab

Tags: matlab, random, parallel-processing

I am running two different codes which generate the same amount of random numbers (thousands of them). 
I was trying to keep the same path of random numbers on both codes using:

```
rng('default') 
rng(1);
```

However, I am almost sure that the random numbers being generated are different. 
Can it be due to the fact that I am using a `parfor` loop?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is due to the `parfor`. This happens because `parfor` does not iterate the loop in a successive order, but in a random order as distributed per worker. So you do have the same random numbers (probably), but permuted in a random way.

Comment: Hum. Thanks for your comment. Any workaround on that? (e.g. force parfor to iterate loop in successive order?)

Comment: You can't, that's the nature of `parfor`. If you require your loop to be iterated in the same order, use `for`. Besides, thousands of iterations is very low for `parfor`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32146555/saving-time-and-memory-using-parfor-in-matlab/32146700#32146700

Comment: Now that I think of it, what you can probably do (without seeing your code) is to initialise a random array *before* the `parfor`, then let each loop call a value from that array.

Comment: Actually, the parfor on my case allows me to reduce code time from 8 hours to approximately 2 hours, so it is a significant difference. 
I though about that but there are way to many random variables being generated on my code (around 500*300*2*2). Some are from uniform distributions, some from normals with different variances and means, Also, the result of uniform random generator impacts the variance of the normal that I want to draw next ...

Comment: @Adriaan, do you think something along the lines of the last post on the thread below would solve it?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17111111/matlab-how-to-set-random-seed-in-parfor-to-produce-same-results-as-serial-for

Comment: Seem like a duplicate to this post even. Should work.